# Simple Mouth Rigging

Tags: rigging

[image]

I'm having big problems rigging this characters mouth, it's really simple the mouth itself, and I want to do it with bones and not shapekeys.

The lips and the body are the same object.

Comment: So what are the big problems specifically? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Please  Add images that show how you set your bones and weights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty much just *start your bones at the edge of the mouth* and work your way in, leaving a gap in the middle for size difference when the edges of the mouth move out.

[image]
I recommend using some sort of mouth animation reference sheet and choosing which shapes the mouth will be taking on most often, especially if your creature doesn't speak a human language where mouth movements are fairly non-caricatured and straight forward. This rigging system, however should do for a basis of most things, and with a little tweaking and weight-painting can be made much less scabby, however the immediate results aren't terrible :)

[image]

Obviously include more bones around areas that will need greater control over their deformation and do not forget about that gap in the middle of the lip.

Comment: Really good answer, and the gif is great too.  Thanks @Scalia!